# force CamelCase on domain name in browser's address bar

Tags: dns, camelcasing

Can I force a domain name to appear CamelCase in the browser's address bar? All browsers seem to force lowercase on the domain. Can this be accomplished with the `.htaccess` file... or some other means?

I'm generally fine with the all lowercase default, but have a client who has asked, and would like to give a definitive answer.

Comment: In IE8 and Chrome5, the "Host" header from the client is always lowercase so you won't be able to detect that this is a problem even if you could control it.

Comment: @David. Your comment is the most valuable piece of information resulting from my question. I wish it was an answer rather than a comment so I could accept it.

Comment: 2019: A few years ago I was able to do this using a hack of sorts.  Although I can't recall it exactly, I found it from a user (not se).  Essentially it was to serve 404 at the lowercase url and forward with masking to the uppercase.  I may be missing something.  Afair it worked in all major browsers except Safari.  It may be that other browsers auto-redirected to lowercase but didn't think to auto-display lowercase.  That was 2017 and idk if this hack still works, but wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't since its so easy to fix (although somehow major browsers didnt for years)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been unable to find any way to accomplish this. Apparently, it can not be done.

Comment: You don't say why you have come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

Your client is clearly concerned about an aspect of the web that they do not understand and sadly for them cannot change.

Without using an IDN upper case chars are forbidden in domain names by standards as upper case and lower case are treated without significance.

You cannot do this sensibly in all browsers, sorry.

You *might* be able to buy an internationalized domain name and make use of Homographs[1] to represent upper case chars. But this is clearly daft and requires your end-user to have a browser that will support this properly

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack

Comment: And for those browsers that *won't* show the IDN properly (for security reasons), you'll see Punycode instead. If your client has a problem with lower case letters, he'll *definitely* have a problem with Punycode.

Comment: -1 and flagged. It is a reasonable technical question. I have great respect for my client, and do not appreciate your disparaging them.

Comment: @kingjeffrey: I think you're taking Ian's answer too personally.  It's an idiom; I'm sure he's not suggesting that your client literally be committed.

Comment: @Michael who has respect for clients?  They interfere between the computer-chair interface.

Comment: @Michael, it was clear Ian did not literally think my client was certifiably insane. He just thought them an ass. To this, I take offense. The tone of this answer is unnecessarily confrontational, and uncharacteristic of what I have experienced at stackoverflow.

Comment: @IanNorton, thank you for editing your answer. I have removed my down vote. For context, my client was not demanding or unreasonable. They just asked if it was technically possible. If the answer is no (as it appears to be), I am sure they will give me no grief.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking why the client wants camel case in browser's address bar? My guess is that their requirement is different from wanting to force camel case :)

Comment: It was not a requirement, it was a request relating to their branding.